# What are best practices for cross browser/platform testing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cross-browser-testing

I have to perform cross-browser testing on different platforms. So before to start just want to know the important points that need to be taken care of.

Answer (score 6):

Multi-device/browser testing strategy

Above all else:

#### Know your user population and the devices they use and the way they use them

1. Determine if your focus is manual or automation testing as they have different requirements
2. Find out what browsers, devices & versions are used by *your* users (server logs, new relic, etc.)
3. Ask the business what percent of traffic needs to be supported.  Make sure you use %'s and not versions like "IE6" becuase version traffic is always changing (constantly decreasing for old versions)
4. Explain why "all users must be served" will cripple modern development and interfaces (e.g. spending 50% of your development on 0.01% of your customers is a no-win situation compared to competitors). There are *thousands* of android devices and no-one tests them all.
5. Determine whether you want an in-house testing lab vs cloud testing vendors such as Browserstack and Sauce Labs
6. Determine the business needs and future plans.  For example if the current audience is only 25% mobile - but expected to grow to 75% mobile over the next 2 years you would want to take that into account when developing for and testing on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

these are the best practices I would recommend to you should follow:

> **Precaution:** Before starting, it might be helpful to create a matrix that maps out all the combinations of browsers, devices, and
> operating systems you plan to test. This will help in organizing your
> testing efforts and ensuring that no critical combination is missed.

**Choose Your Browser and Device:** Find out which browsers and which devices are most popular with your target market. To prioritize which browsers and devices to test on, use analytics tools or market share information. Remember to include various browser versions, particularly ones with a reputation for having backward compatibility problems.

**Operating Systems and Versions:** Different browsers can behave differently on different operating systems. Make sure to test on various OS versions, especially if you are supporting platforms like Windows, macOS, Linux, iOS, and Android.

**Browser Settings and Extensions:** Browsers with different settings (like zoom levels or privacy modes) and extensions can affect how your application behaves. Try to include some tests with common extensions installed and with default settings altered.

**Responsive Design:** Ensure your application's responsive design works seamlessly across different screen sizes and orientations. Use emulators and real devices for accurate testing (or you may use browser stack or lambda test Platform for device testing).

**Functionality Testing:** All functional flows should be tested across browsers. Issues often arise in areas like form submissions, authentication flows, and data processing.

**Performance Testing:** Check how your application performs under different browsers. Performance can vary due to rendering engines, so it’s crucial to measure load times, scripting speed, and responsiveness.

**Security Aspects:** Cross-browser tests should also cover security considerations. Different browsers handle security settings and warnings differently, so be attentive to how your application maintains security across them.

**JavaScript and CSS Compatibility:** Since browsers interpret JavaScript and CSS differently, verify that all features work correctly and are styled consistently. Tools like Babel for JavaScript transpilation and PostCSS for CSS compatibility can help.

**Automation:** To save time and improve reliability, automate repetitive tests. Tools like Selenium WebDriver/Cypress etc

can help you automate browser tests across different platforms.

**Error Logging and Analysis:** Implement a robust error-logging mechanism to capture browser-specific issues. This can help in quick identification and rectification of cross-browser compatibility issues.